# Alternatives for 3 lines of java-like code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume you have a function, that sometimes returns a value, and sometimes doesn't, because there really is nothing you could return in this case, not even a default value or something. Now you want to do something with the result, but of course **only** when there is one.

Example:

```
result = function_call(params)
if result:
    print result
```

Is there a way to write this in a more pythonic way, maybe even in one line?

Like that:

```
print function_call(params) or #nothing
```

(Note that I mean it shouldn't print "nothing" or "None". It should actually just **not** print at all, if the result is `None`)

Comment: A requirement is no setup, I assume? If setup code is OK, you could make a function for that. Especially easy to integrate in py3 where print is a function itself.

Comment: Isn't it 3 lines of Python-like code? We can usually replace 3 lines of _Java_ code with about 1/3 of a line of Python :)

Comment: Yes @gnibbler, `if something:` lines are a big part of what is very Java-like and can be often written better in python.

Comment: @erikb85, porting just 3 lines at a time doesn't give much chance to leverage the power of Python.

Comment: @gnibbler: I am not porting. And yes, I just want to improve this little detail in my skillset. I do that often, so my python code improves step by step over the years. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; in Python, name binding is a statement and so cannot be used as an expression within a statement.  Since `print` is also a statement you're going to require 3 lines; in Python 3 you could write:

```
result = function_call(params)
print(result) if result else None
```

This isn't quite true for name binding within a comprehension or generator, where name binding is a syntax item that has statement-like semantics:

```
[print(result) for result in generator_call(params) if result]
```

As Kos says, you can abuse this to create a one-element comprehension:

```
[print(result) for result in (function_call(params), ) if result]
```

Another syntax item that performs name binding and can similarly be abused is the `lambda` expression:

```
(lambda result: print(result) if result else None)(function_call(params))
```

Note that in both these cases the operation on the return value must be an expression and not a statement.

Comment: +1; you can make that `for result in (function_call(params),)`.

Comment: That's more code golf than pythonic refactoring though. The 3 line version is significantly more readable.

Comment: At first I thought `print(result) if result else None` would print `None`, but I was wrong. It's actually working!

Comment: @erikb85, that's because the first part (`print(result)`) is only evaluated if the check condition (`if result`) evaluates to `True`. Otherwise `None` is evaluated - which, obviously evaluates to `None` :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the more Pythonic version is actually closer to your original:

```
result = function_call(params)
if result is not None:
    do_something(result)
```

Checking for `is (not) None` seems very idiomatic to me - I've used it several times myself and I've also seen it used elsewhere[citation-needed].

Comment: Depends if you want to do_something is result is an empty string/list/etc. or not. +1 for just sticking with the 3 lines

Comment: This is very expressive in terms of "what happens here", but not in terms of "what did the author want to do here". It's a completely valid response, yet just not my personal taste for python code.

Comment: @erikb85, as I mentioned, I believe the Pythonic standard is to return `None` when there's no viable result (see [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for one example).

Answer (score -1):

From the answers up to now I would do that:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function #if Python2.7
>>> def filtered_print(txt):
...    txt and print(txt)
...
>>> filtered_print('hello world')
hello world
>>> filtered_print('None')
None
>>> filtered_print(None)
>>>
```

If someone else has a better solution in mind, I am still open for alternatives, though!

Comment: Note that someone downvoted this, because he thinks, it is bad style to write code in `A and B` style instead of 2 lines with an `if`. I think it's not dangerous and a lot of people will understand this code quite fine. Depending on the people you work with you might choose **not** to use this solution!

Comment: Finally I decided against this, because the marked solution works and looks better.